# marquee textview stop and restart moving to the first word of the string when next video is played in my videoview

Tags: android, video

Sorry, I'm still learning android programming and i need your help to this marquee textview (info) will stop and restarted to the first character of the string once a next video is played. And i have also a problem with my videoview when all video was finished played it did not loop back to the first video. 
Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



             //Clock Widgets
            c = new Clock();
            v = new Video();
            fn = new Filenames();

            time = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time);
            date = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.date);
            info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
            info.setSelected(true);


            mHandler.post(r);


                vidPlayer = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
                media_Controller = new MediaController(this);
                playvideos();
           }        

        public void playvideo(ArrayList<String> filename, int index){

              v.setFilename(filename.get(index));
              vidPlayer.setVideoURI(v.getVideoURI());
              vidPlayer.start();
              vidPlayer.setMediaController(media_Controller);

    }

    public void playvideos(){

        playvideo(fn.GetFileNames(),index);


        vidPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                info.setSelected(true);
                if(fn.GetFileNames().get(++index)!=null){

                    playvideo(fn.GetFileNames(),index);

                }
                else{
                    index=0;
                    mp.reset();
                    mp.setLooping(true);
                }


            }
        });

    }


My xml in (info) textview:

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/info"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
```